# Angular4: how to access constants in html as href?

Tags: angular

I work on angular4. My project has a constant file and that file has an `emailURL`. I have to access `emailURL` on my HTML page but chrome throws an error `Template parse error`. Below is my code

constant.ts

```
export const CONST_CLASS{
'emailURL':'http://someting.com?mail='
}
```

HTML

```
<a href=" '{{MY_CONST_CLASS.emailURL}}' + useremail">Username</a>
```

TS

```
import { CONST_CLASS } from '../constants';

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class MyTestComponent implements OnInit {

  public MY_CONST_CLASS = CONST_CLASS;

  // ...
}
```

I also tried below 2 synatx but URL is not getting formed correctly. Please guide me where did I go wrong.

```
<a href="{{MY_CONST_CLASS.emailURL}}+ useremail">Username</a>
```

and

```
<a href="'MY_CONST_CLASS.emailURL' + useremail">Username</a>
```

Comment: What kind of error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
<a [href]="MY_CONST_CLASS.emailURL + useremail">Username</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{MY_CONST_CLASS.emailURL}}{{useremail}}">Username</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{{MY_CONST_CLASS.emailURL + usermail}}">Username</a>
```

that all assumes that your TS component has `usermail` field defined.

```
export class MyTestComponent implements OnInit {

  public MY_CONST_CLASS = CONST_CLASS;   
  usermail="set it here or somewhere else in component's code";   

// ... }
```

Comment: <a [href]="MY_CONST_CLASS.emailURL + useremail">Username</a>

worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Accept the answer in such case.